# Cannot compile a simple project by command line

Tags: shell, scala

I have a simple toy project made of two classes:

```
object A {
    var b = B()
}

class B {
....
}
```

I cannot use any IDE, because I need to use `ssh`.

I cannot compile the project because of the error:

```
A.scala:18: error: not found: value B
```

I compile using:

```
scalac *.scala
```

I tried to play around with the classpath but that did not solve.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't defined a [companion object](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics2.html#object) for `B`, when you instantiate it, you need `new B()` instead of just `B()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to instantiate class `B` by using `var b = B()`, you'll need to create a companion object for class `B` with an `apply()` factory method:

```
class B {
  // ...
}

object B {
  def apply(): B = new B()
}
```

Note that `B()` is special syntax for `B.apply()`.

Another way is to make `B` a case class:

```
case class B {
  // ...
}
```

Then a companion object with an `apply` method is automatically generated (as well as a `toString` and methods for pattern matching).